# Generating Divs with unique buttons for toggling hide/show

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

Im making a contacts book, and with each new entry it generates a Div with all the information inside. I have gotten as far as giving each generated div a unique ID, and each button generated with the Div a unique ID, however I am having trouble associating the buttons with the div and allowing it to perform functions (such as toggling the visibility of the div).

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated, as I will soon be bald from frustration.

### Updated Code with suggestions

### The code that generates the DIV and Button:

```
 Contact.prototype.generateDiv = function(){

      divid = divid + 1;
      buttonid = buttonid + 1;
     var control = [];
     control[0] = divid;
     control[1] = buttonid;
     myControls.push(control);

var childDiv =
            "<div style='border-style:double;border-width:6px;background-color: #2f4f4f;margin-left:auto;max-width: 700px;margin-right: auto;text-shadow:-1px -1px 1mm #000,1px -1px 1mm #000,-1px 1px 1mm #000,1px 1px 1mm #000;'>" +
            this.firstName + " " + this.surname + "<button class='btnForDiv' style='color: black;' id='" + buttonid + "'" + "> Button </button>" +
            "<div  id='" +  divid  + "' " +  "style='margin-right: auto;margin-left :40px;width: 300px;border-right-style: double;border-right-width:3px;'>" +
            "<br>" + "Surname: "  +  this.surname + "<BR>" + "First Name:" + this.firstName + "<br>" +
            "Date Of Birth: " +  this.days + "/" +  this.months + "/" + this.years + "/" + "<br>" + "Telephone Number: " + this.phone +
            "<br>" + "Address: " + this.address + " " + this.post + "<br>" + "Email Address: " + this.email + "<br>" + "Group: " + this.group +
            "<br>" + "Days Until Birthday: " + this.daysUntil + "<BR>" +  "</div>" +  "</div>"


        return childDiv  ;
```

}

### The entire code

```
var surnameField,firstNameField,birthdayField, phoneField, addressField, postField, emailField, groupField ;  //Declaring variables for the fields

var Contact = function(surname,firstName,date, phone , address , post, email, group){
    this.surname = surname ;
    this.firstName = firstName ;
    this.birthdayDate = new Date (date) ;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.address= address;
    this.email = email;
    this.post = post;
    this.group = group;
    this.selected = false ;

}

var contacts = [];
divid = 0;
buttonid = 1000;
myControls = [];

var getDate = function() {

    for (var i= 0, j=contacts.length;i<j;i++){
        var y = contacts[i].birthdayDate.getFullYear();
        var m = contacts[i].birthdayDate.getMonth();
       var d = contacts[i].birthdayDate.getDate();
        contacts[i].days = d;
        contacts[i].months = m + 1;
        contacts[i].years = y ;
        var today = new Date() ;
        var ty = today.getFullYear();
        contacts[i].bdThisYear = new Date(ty,m,d, 0 , 0 , 0);

    }
}

var daysUntilBirthday = function(){
    for (var i= 0, j=contacts.length;i<j;i++){
        var today = new Date() ;
            contacts[i].daysUntil = Math.round((contacts[i].bdThisYear - today ) /1000/60/60/24+1);
            if (contacts[i].daysUntil <= 0){
            contacts[i].daysUntil =  contacts[i].daysUntil + 365 ;
        }
    }
}

Contact.prototype.generateDiv = function(){

          divid = divid + 1;
          buttonid = buttonid + 1;
         var control = [];
         control[0] = divid;
         control[1] = buttonid;
         myControls.push(control);

    var childDiv =
                "<div style='border-style:double;border-width:6px;background-color: #2f4f4f;margin-left:auto;max-width: 700px;margin-right: auto;text-shadow:-1px -1px 1mm #000,1px -1px 1mm #000,-1px 1px 1mm #000,1px 1px 1mm #000;'>" +
                this.firstName + " " + this.surname + "<button class='btnForDiv' style='color: black;' id='" + buttonid + "'" + "> Button </button>" +
                "<div  id='" +  divid  + "' " +  "style='margin-right: auto;margin-left :40px;width: 300px;border-right-style: double;border-right-width:3px;'>" +
                "<br>" + "Surname: "  +  this.surname + "<BR>" + "First Name:" + this.firstName + "<br>" +
                "Date Of Birth: " +  this.days + "/" +  this.months + "/" + this.years + "/" + "<br>" + "Telephone Number: " + this.phone +
                "<br>" + "Address: " + this.address + " " + this.post + "<br>" + "Email Address: " + this.email + "<br>" + "Group: " + this.group +
                "<br>" + "Days Until Birthday: " + this.daysUntil + "<BR>" +  "</div>" +  "</div>"


            return childDiv  ;

}



var addContact = function(surnameField,firstNameField,birthdayField, phoneField, addressField, postField, emailField, groupField ){
        if(surnameField.value){
            a = new Contact(surnameField.value, firstNameField.value,birthdayField.value, phoneField.value, addressField.value, postField.value, emailField.value, groupField.value);
            contacts.push(a);
        }else{ alert("Please complete all fields")}

}

var clearUI = function(){
    var white = "#fff";
    surnameField.value = "";
    surnameField.style.backgroundColor = white;
    firstNameField.value = "";
    firstNameField.style.backgroundColor = white;
    birthdayField.value="";
    birthdayField.style.backgroundColor = white;
    phoneField.value = "";
    phoneField.style.backgroundcolor = white;
    addressField.value = "";
    addressField.style.backgroundcolor = white;
    postField.value = "";
    postField.style.backgroundcolor = white;
    emailField.value = "";
    emailField.style.backgroundcolor = white;
    groupField.value="";
    groupField.style.backgroundcolor = white;
}


var updateList = function(){
    divid = 0;
    buttonid = 1000;
    myControls = []
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("parentDiv"),
        cDiv = "<BR>" +  "<div align='center'> Click a contact to expand</div>" ;

    for (var i= 0, j=contacts.length;i<j;i++){
        var cntct = contacts[i];
        cDiv += cntct.generateDiv();
    }

    tableDiv.innerHTML = cDiv;
    getDate();
    daysUntilBirthday();
    saveContacts();
}

var add = function(){
;
    addContact(surnameField,firstNameField,birthdayField, phoneField, addressField, postField, emailField, groupField);
    clearUI();
    daysUntilBirthday();
    getDate();
    updateList();
};

var saveContacts = function(){
    var cntcts = JSON.stringify(contacts);
    if (cntcts !==""){
        localStorage.contacts = cntcts;
    }else{
        alert("Could not save contacts");
    }
}

var loadContacts = function(){
    var cntcts = "";
    if(localStorage.contacts !== undefined){
        cntcts = localStorage.contacts;
        contacts = JSON.parse(cntcts);
        var proto = new Contact();
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++){
            var cntct = contacts[i]
            cntct.__proto__ = proto;
            cntct.birthdayDate = new Date(cntct.birthdayDate);
        }
    }
}

var clearContacts = function(){
    contacts = [];
    updateList();

}

//var periodUpdate = function(){
//    setInterval(updateList, 10000);
//}




window.onload = function(){
    loadContacts();
    updateList();
    surnameField = document.getElementById("surname");
    firstNameField = document.getElementById("firstName")
    birthdayField = document.getElementById("birthday");
    phoneField = document.getElementById("phone");
    addressField = document.getElementById("address");
    postField = document.getElementById("post");
    emailField = document.getElementById("email");
    groupField = document.getElementById("group");
    addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
    addButton.onclick = add;
    delButton = document.getElementById("delButton");
    delButton.onclick = clearContacts;
    clearUI();
   // periodUpdate();
}
```

### The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="contacts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        (".btnForDiv").on("click", function(){

    // get the ID of the button
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    var divid;
    // now find the div Id related to this button
    for (var i = 0, len = myControls.length; i < len; i++){
    if (myControls[i][1] == id){
    divid = myControls[i][0];
    break;
    }
    }

    // you now have the div,so toggle it.
    $("#" + divid).toggle();

    });
    });
    </script>

    <div><title>Contacts Book</title></div>

</head>

<body>
<div class="information">
<heading><h1>Contacts Book</h1></heading>
</div>
<p><div class="information">Enter the contacts details below and click Add or select to view an existing contact.</div></p>
<hr>

<div class="entrydiv">
<table class="entryforms">
    <br>
    <tr>
        <td>Surname</td><td><input type="text" class="inputboxes"  id="surname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" class="inputboxes"  id="firstName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Birthday</td><td><input type="date" class="inputboxes" id="birthday" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone Number</td><td><input type="text" class="inputboxes" id="phone"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email Address</td><td><input type="text" class="inputboxes"  id="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td><td><input type="text" class="inputboxes" id="address"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Postcode</td><td><input type="text" class="inputboxes"  id="post"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Group</td><td><select class="inputboxes"  id="group"/>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Educational">Educational</option>
        <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>
<button id="addButton">Add Contact</button>
<button id="delButton">Delete Contacts</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="tablediv">
<h2 class="information" align="center">Contacts</h2>
<div  id="parentDiv"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### The Solution

First of all massive thanks to Darren for his advice, which turns out to be spot on (with minor change)

First error I made was inserting jquery, I had

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js">
   //code
</script>
```

When I needed

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     //code
   </script>
```

So that very minor mistake held me back for a while.

Secondly I used:

```
 $(document).on('click','.btnForDiv',function(){
```

To call the Onclick event for my btnForDiv class buttons and the rest was all Darren :)

Thanks again

Comment: Just to clarify - are you struggling to know which div should be controlled by which button?

Comment: No, each div when created is also created alongside a button which im trying to use to toggle the visibility of the div. Im mainly having trouble associating functions with buttons and divs that are created by the script, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Not fully sure what your intent is, so trying to guess. I added an answer - let me know if this is the sort of thing you mean..

Comment: You have an error in your `(".btnForDiv").on` - it should be `$(".btnForDiv").on`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a few things here.

One idea would be to store your generated `div` and `button` ID's in an array. You can then search this array for a given `button` ID to find its corresponding `div`.

For example (not tested...)

```
     // outside your generatedDiv method
     var myControls = new Array();

     // then inside your generatedDiv method
     var control = new Array();
     control[0] = divId;
     control[1] = buttonId;
     myControls.push(control);
```

When you click your `button` you can grab its ID then search through the `myControls` array and look for the corresponding `div`

you could do a single function in jQuery to handle all the `click` for all of your generated buttons.

again (not tested) - give all your buttons a class, for example `btnForDiv`

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

           $(".btnForDiv").click(function(){

              // get the ID of the button
              var id = $(this).prop("id");
              var divId;
              // now find the div Id related to this button
              for (var i = 0, len = myControls.length; i < len; i++){
                if (myControls[i][1] == id){
                   divId = myControls[i][0];
                   break;
                }
              }

              // you now have the div,so toggle it.
              $("#" + divId).toggle();

           });
     });
```

I'm not 100% sure what your question was, though took a stab in the dark to help..

**UPDATE**

Because your `div`'s are generated and added to the DOM dynamically you may have to use `on` instead of `click` - this will bind the `click` event to dynamic elements.

So try this:

```
$(".btnForDiv").on("click", function(){

      // get the id.... etc...

});
```

also, make sure you did add the class `btnForDiv` to your dynamically generated buttons

```
this.firstName + " " + this.surname + "<button style='color: black;' id='" + buttonid +  "b'" + " class='btnForDiv'> Button </button>" +
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response, implementing now. The array works so far it seems, do I put the Jquery stuff into the html with a script tag linking to jquery yeah?

Comment: yep, the `jquery` would normally go between your `<head></head>` tags inside a `<script></script>` tag. Be sure to link to the `jquery` file - not sure if you have it on your page already..

Comment: Hi and thanks for the update! ive added everything as you have said but no action still when clicking the buttons, and no errors still in the console, ill update my original post with the updated versions

Comment: try putting an alert inside the jquery function; make sure it's actually being fired. As I mentioned in the answer , the code is for example only. It's not meant as a full working copy. It's to give you the idea of how to solve your problem.

Comment: Added an alert after the toggle line and again before the break, neither fired when the button was clicked

Comment: put the alert as first line inside the function. Means it's not being reached. If your using jquery version less than 1.7 change `on` to `live`

Comment: Tried having it just call an alert on button click, still nothing, confusing

Comment: If your using jquery version less than 1.7 change on to live. Either way, as mentioned, this is an example.

Comment: Its Jquery 1.8.2, thanks for all your help :) ill keep working with the example and see what i can get going

Comment: If this answer gets you up and running, please mark it as answered - helps future visitors. Thanks

Comment: Solved! Added to original post, thanks agai for all your help :)